# proper formatting of python multiline [ for in ] statement

Tags: python, coding-style, pep8, pep

How should i format a long **for in** statement in python ?

```
for param_one, param_two, param_three, param_four, param_five in get_params(some_stuff_here, and_another stuff):
```

I have found that i can brake a **for in** statement only with a **backslash** :

```
for param_one, param_two, param_three, param_four, param_five \
in get_params(some_stuff_here, and_another_stuff):
```

But my linter has issues with this formatting , what is a *Pythonic* way of
formatting statements like this ?

Comment: there is nothing wrong with the for statement as it is

Comment: If you really have numbered parameters, do this: `for params in get_params(some_stuff_here, and_another_stuff): foo(params[0]); bar(params[1])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
all_params = get_params(some_stuff_here, and_another_stuff)
for param_one, param_two, param_three, param_four, param_five in all_params:
    pass
```

Or you could move the target list inside the loop:

```
for params in get_params(some_stuff_here, and_another_stuff):
    param_one, param_two, param_three, param_four, param_five = params
    pass
```

Or combine both.

Comment: Challenge 2: `get_params` itself is long with many parameters :D

Comment: +1 I was going to write up your second suggestion and just decided to upvote instead.

Answer (score 5):

You can take advantage of the implicit line joining inside parentheses (as recommended in PEP-8):

```
for (param_one, param_two, 
     param_three, param_four, 
     param_five) in get_params(some_stuff_here, 
                               and_another stuff):
```

(Obviously, you can choose how long to make each line and whether or not you need to include line breaks in each set of parentheses.)

---

Looking at this 8+ years later, I would break up the long single logical line in the first place, rather than trying to split the whole thing across multiple physical lines. For example (much like [@poke does](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25228719/1126841)),

```
for t in get_params(some_stuff_here,
                    and_other_stuff):
    (param_one,
     param_two,
     param_three,
     param_four, param_five) = t
```

Comment: Ah, wrapping the "whole" bit after the `for` does not work because then it includes the `in`. The left-hand (between `for` and `in`) and the right-hand (between `in` and `:` (colon)) sides of the assignment must be separate. Makes sense now.

Comment: Parentheses can only wrap *expressions*, unless otherwise allowed by Python's grammar. Implicit line-joining is a side-effect of parentheses, not the reason they exist.